# I am using MySQL. I need to execute the query which is fetched from a table

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3

I am using ruby on rails.
Hence through my controller I am fetching the list of data(query strings saved in the database) on the basis of some condition. Now I need to execute these queries.
Do any one know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Atfirst store the fetched data to a variable.
Than

```
@var = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_values(tableA.query)
```